# Rate (probability) based selection

Tags: php, math, probability, rate

Let's suppose I have a structured array like that:

```
[
  'A' => 2,
  'B' => 0,
  'C' => 0,
  'D' => 1,
  'E' => 1,
  'F' => 0
]
```

I'll refer to this structure as "categories", so, I have six categories in this array.
And my goal is to pick a random product based in a category.

I want to do a *rate-based* category selection, and as I know, I have to calculate how many percent this category represents in array, for example:

```
<?php

// ...

$total = array_sum($a);

array_map(function ($hits) use ($total) {
  return $hits / $total;
}, ...);
```

This will give me something like that:

```
(
    [A] => 0.5  (50%)
    [B] => 0
    [C] => 0
    [D] => 0.25 (25%)
    [E] => 0.25 (25%)
    [F] => 0
)
```

Okay, now I have to do a simple algorithm to get the category based on those rates; I think I  need now to pick a random number between range `(0, 1)`, and make some "slices", for example:

```
0    .. 0.50   => A
0.50 .. 0.25   => D
0.75 .. 1      => E
```

And if the random number is between `0` and `0.50`, I will pick category `A`, if between `0.50` and `0.75` then `D`, if between `0.75` and `1` then `E`, of course, is what I'm doing right now.

### The problem

If I go this way, I'm totally saying mathematically and logically that I'll never get `B`, `C` nor `F`, because there is no hits on those categories (no slices then.)

How I can avoid this? I have to give some chances to those categories, but minimal (which means is not impossible).

Comment: Well you could f.e. _add_ a value of `1` to each category value in your first array … meaning `A` would have a value of `3` afterwards, `b` would have `1`, and so on … that would stop your empty categories from resulting in empty “slices” later on.

Comment: If you think that puts to much emphasis on empty categories, then chose a different “algorithm” – f.e. _multiply_ each value by `2`, `5` or `10`, _before_ adding `1`; that would put more emphasis on categories that are not empty to begin with. I’d suggest you do some test runs with different variations, let’s say 10.000 “draws” each – and then you look at the results and figure out which version gives results that you “like” best …

Comment: Expanding what @CBroe is saying, you could use formula `(coefficient) = 1.0 / ( (sum of categories) * (minimal probability) )` to select a specific minimal probability. Though experimentation may still be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a distribution array which will have each category repeated `hits` times. Then you can simply get a random element from that array.

Somehow like this:

```
$distr = array();
array_walk($a, function ($hits, $cate) use ($distr) {
  $distr = array_merge($distr, array_fill(0, $hits, $cate));
});

$index = mt_rand(0, count($distr) - 1);
$random_cate = $distr[$index];
```

Comment: It's not a "random element", there's some rates, I can't simply "get a random one".

Comment: @Andrey Knupp Vital Assuming each category repeated in `$distr` array the same number of times as given in original array, it could give you the desired result

Comment: You're right, sorry. I got your idea right now. I've modified your code, see: https://gist.github.com/andreyknupp/c36cf9ef42747879f9d6

The result is the number of appearances, can I improve performance? do you have some tips?

Comment: @Andrey Knupp Vital I think you can separate code of `$distr` array creation from `categ` function. So it will be populated only once.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a random variable X that will take one of the values in S = {A, B, C, D, E, F}.

P(X = A) = 1/2
P(X = B) = 0
etc.

Define a new uniform random variable Y for which P(Y = A) = P(Y = B) = ... = P(Y = F) = 1 / |S| and a random variable Z = X if T = 0 and Z = Y if T = 1, where T is a Bernoulli random variable with P(T = 1) = t and P(T = 0) = 1 - t.

Then for all s in S,

P(Z = s) = P(Z = s | T = 0) P(T = 0) + P(Z = s | T = 1) P(T = 1) = (1 - t) P(X = s) + t / |S|

Using this model, all you need to choose is the parameter t in [0,1], where t indicates the probability of a uniform random selection out of S. t = 0 is your current model, where B, C, and F will never occur.